# Вытянуть данные из массива и записать в новый массив. PHP

Tags: php, массивы

Есть массив $event - это матчи выбранной лиги, нужно разбить матчи на - состоявщиеся, не состоявшиеся но с датой, не состоявшиеся без даты. Делаю так:

```
$match_event = [];
    foreach ($events as $e) {
        
      if (isset($e['LuUT'])) {  // Матч еще не состоялся но есть дата матча
        $match_event = ['whait'=> $e,];
      }
      if (!isset($e['LuUT']) && isset($e['Tr1'])) {   // Матч состоялся
        $match_event = ['true' => $e,];
      }
      if (!isset($e['LuUT']) && !isset($e['Tr1'])) {  // Матч еще не состоялся нету даты
         $match_event = ['false' => $e,];
      }
      //dd($e);
    }
  
    dd($match_event);
```

Получаю array:1 [▼
"false" => array:3
Это не правильно так как там есть еще и состоявшиеся матчи, нужно еще форичем пройти по $e? Или как правильно вытянуть. Сам массив такого вида:

```
array:2 [▼
  0 => array:35 [▼
    0 => array:15 [▼
      "T1" => array:1 [▶]
      "Tr1" => "0"
      "Trh1" => "0"
      "T2" => array:1 [▶]
      "Tr2" => "5"
      "Trh2" => "1"
      "IDs" => array:1 [▶]
      "Sg" => 1
      "Esd" => 20200923230000
      "Esid" => 6
      "Epr" => 2
      "Eps" => "FT"
      "Ewt" => 2
      "Ern" => 3
      "EO" => 8227
    ]
    1 => array:19 [▶]
    2 => array:15 [▶]
```

Comment: Вы в следующий раз приводите маленький пример нормального массива, который лежит в переменной. Ваш пример нельзя скопировать и тестировать в редакторе, его приходится править... И вот 10 раз подумаешь, отвечать или ну его.

Answer (score 0):

Вы не правильно понимаете логику работы с массивами.

Вот решение:

```html
$match_event = [
    'wait' => [], // Матчи еще не состоялись, но есть дата матчей
    'true' => [], // Матчи состоялись
    'false' => [] // Матчи еще не состоялись и нету даты
];

foreach ($events as $e) {

    if (isset($e['LuUT'])) {  // Матч еще не состоялись но есть дата матча
        $match_event['wait'][] = $e;
    }

    if (!isset($e['LuUT']) && isset($e['Tr1'])) {   // Матч состоялся
        $match_event['true'][] = $e;
    }

    if (!isset($e['LuUT']) && !isset($e['Tr1'])) {  // Матч еще не состоялся нету даты
        $match_event['false'][] = $e;
    }

}

dd($match_event);
```

Comment: Я получаю вот такой массив, некорректный, так как там есть Tr1, по условию в false он не должен попадать
array:3 [▼
  "wait" => []
  "true" => []
  "false" => array:2 [▼
    0 => array:35 [▼
      0 => array:15 [▼
        "T1" => array:1 [▶]
        "Tr1" => "0"
        "Trh1" => "0"
        "T2" => array:1 [▶]
        "Tr2" => "5"
        "Trh2" => "1"
        "Sg" => 1
        "Esd" => 20200923230000
        "Esid" => 6
        "Epr" => 2
        "Eps" => "FT"
        "Ewt" => 2
        "Ern" => 3
        "EO" => 8227
      ]
      1 => array:19 [▶]

Answer (score 0):

У вас все верно, кроме того, что вы в цикле перебираете не тот уровень массива. Вам нужен этот уровень - `$events[0]`:

```
$events = [
    0 => [  // вот этот подмассив нам нужно перебирать в цикле!
        0 => [
            "Trh2" => "1",
            "Sg" => 1,
            "Tr1" => 234,
            "Esd" => 111,
        ],
        1 => [
            "Trh2" => "1",
            "Sg" => 1,
            "Esd" => 222,
        ],
        2 => [
            "Trh2" => "1",
            "Sg" => 1,
            "Esd" => 333,
            "LuUT" => 'something'
        ]
    ]
];
```

Далее, как уже ответили, создаете массив пустой для результатов:

```
/** создаем пустой массив для текущих событий: */
$match_event = ['wait' => [], 'true' => [], 'false' => []];
```

Дальше перебором исходного заполняем новый, как и у вас в примере, в принципе:

```
/**
 * в цикле обрабатываем исходные данные.
 * в исходном массиве данные о матчах находятся здесь: $events[0], как было указано выше в комментарии.
 */
foreach ($events[0] as $event) {
    if (isset($event['LuUT'])) {
        $match_event['wait'][] = $event;
    } else {
        $key = isset($event['Tr1']) ? 'true' : 'false';
        $match_event[$key][] = $event;
    }
}

echo '<pre>'.print_r($match_event, true).'</pre>';
```